# Problem when creating Asynchronous Pluggable Protocol on Vista

Tags: windows, protocols, network-protocols

I have created a tutorial for creating a dzone protocol (so that I can type dzone:n in firefox to get the new links for example), it works great but when at the end I want to create a new alias protocol dn which points to the same handler, Vista doesn't want to take this new path though registry entry is ok (I check by renaming dn to dzone).

See tutorial here:
**[http://reboltutorial.com/blog/dzone-protocol/]**

This problem doesn't occur in Windows XP only on Vista

Answer (score 0):

OK finally I have tested in Internet Explorer it works, it did also work on previous version of Firefox, so it seems to be a firefox 3.0.11 bug.